# Always on top Adobe Air

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I know about nativeWindow.alwaysInFront property and I do use it, however if another application creates a window which is set to be topmost as well, it does overlay my AIR app. For example, Teamviewer message windows.

Is there a way to achieve absolute topmost-ness ?

Answer (score 0):

No.

But setting alwaysInFront to false, and to true again, will put your app on top again.